# React Native backend server start error

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, facebook-login, backend

I want to use log in with facebook and google option in my app. I use a node.js backend server for this. But backend doesn't  run. every time when I run npm start it returns error.

I follow a tutorial for this.

Tutorial link [Here](https://rationalappdev.com/logging-into-react-native-apps-with-facebook-or-google/)

Code of server.js file

```js
    const transformFacebookProfile = (profile) => ({
  name: profile.name,
  avatar: profile.picture.data.url,
});

// Transform Google profile into user object
const transformGoogleProfile = (profile) => ({
  name: profile.displayName,
  avatar: profile.image.url,
});

// Register Facebook Passport strategy
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(facebook,
  // Gets called when user authorizes access to their profile
  async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
    // Return done callback and pass transformed user object
    => done(null, transformFacebookProfile(profile._json))
));

// Register Google Passport strategy
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(google,
  async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
    => done(null, transformGoogleProfile(profile._json))
));

// Serialize user into the sessions
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user));

// Deserialize user from the sessions
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user));

// Initialize http server
const app = express();

// Initialize Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Set up Facebook auth routes
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/auth/facebook' }),
  // Redirect user back to the mobile app using Linking with a custom protocol OAuthLogin
  (req, res) => res.redirect('OAuthLogin://login?user=' + JSON.stringify(req.user)));

// Set up Google auth routes
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/auth/google' }),
  (req, res) => res.redirect('OAuthLogin://login?user=' + JSON.stringify(req.user)));

// Launch the server on the port 3000
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  const { address, port } = server.address();
  console.log(`Listening at http://${address}:${port}`);
});
```

When I run 'npm start'
[image: cmd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the npm start script you should add "node" at the start:

```
"start": "node node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js"
```

instead of:

```
"start": "node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js"
```